# Matplotlib Plot Dashed Circles

Tags: matplotlib, markers

Given the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.random.randn(60) 
y = np.random.randn(60)
x2 = np.random.randn(60)
y2 = np.random.randn(60)

plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
plt.show()
```

How would I plot this same data with dashed circles instead (where the outline of each circle is dashed instead of solid) for x 2 and y2 only?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I know this can be done with patches as in [here](http://matthiaseisen.com/matplotlib/shapes/circle/), but I need it to be done via plt.scatter if possible because I will also be plotting another set of circles on the same plot and using patches messed with the chart dimensions (was way too thin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass `linestyle='--'` to `scatter`.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, s=80, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r',
            linestyle='--')
```

[image]

For that marker size I would rather use `linestyle=':'` though.

Comment: Thanks, Goyo. Here is the question I should have asked in the first place: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108055/matplotlib-plot-dashed-circles-using-plt-plot-instead-of-plt-scatter