# How to do a scatter plot with empty and dotted dotted borders symbol?

Tags: python, matplotlib, symbols

In Python, with Matplotlib, I now how to draw a scatter plot with empty circles. 
However the goal is to plot empty circles with dotted borders like in the left top corner of the image attached.

[image]

Comment: `linestyle='--'` in the scatter plot is the key thing here to note among others. What you call dotted-dotted looks dashed in your provided figure

Comment: The answer is founded in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108055/matplotlib-plot-dashed-circles-using-plt-plot-instead-of-plt-scatter). using from mathtext  ur'$\u25CC$' THANKS ImportanceOfBeingErnest!!!